# How do I find out which random port Docker has chosen?

Tags: docker

I ran this:

```
$ docker run -p 8080 --rm my_container
```

which I guess maps the container port 8080 to some random available port on the host. But how do I find out which port?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/) command:

```
docker port my_container
```

This command output like the following (example with MySQL image):

```
3306/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:3306
```

The value before `->` specifies the port on the container side. The value after `->` specifies the chosen port on the host machine.

---

You can also run the container with a specific port on the host machine (if available):

```
docker run -p "80:8080" --rm my_container
```

This would give the following output on `docker port`:

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find out by [inspecting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/#list-all-port-bindings) the container (where `$INSTANCE_ID` is your container ID):

```
docker inspect --format='{{range $p, $conf := .NetworkSettings.Ports}} {{$p}} -> {{(index $conf 0).HostPort}} {{end}}' $INSTANCE_ID
```

Or by checking running containers:

```
docker ps | grep container_name_part
```

Or simply list all running containers:

```
docker ps
```

Alternatively you can bind specific port so no random port is chosen `-p 8080:8080`.

Comment: `Template parsing error: template: :1:59: executing "" at <index $conf 0>: error calling index: index of untyped nil`